# Restoring certificate deleted in certmgr.msc on Windows 10 machine

Tags: certificate, windows

Is there a way to restore certificate which was deleted in certmgr.msc from personal store on Windows 10 machine? It does not go to recycle bin and is not a file system level objects to leverage file system recovery tools. Any feasible way to restore deleted certificate in this scenario?

Comment: Restore a full backup (disk image) of the PC from a time where the certificate had not yet been deleted.

Comment: If you have another machine with the same certificate, you could export it from there and import it into the machine with the missing/deleted certificate.

Comment: If you do not have a full backup of the system, or are unable to use a restore point, what you want is not possible.  Is there a reason you cannot simply reinstall the certificate?

Comment: No it is government issued certificate and process was a bit poorly documented, so I ended up with public CRT certificate part only and the only way to get private key part is go through requesting certificate again from scratch - which will take some time and includes physical presence in government office.